# Unique album name for his author

Tags: t-sql, duplicates, unique, uniq

I am trying to make two tables: one for the `author` and one for their music album.

Author can't have more than one album with the same name. It should work once per `author ID` / `name` / whatever.

This should NOT be allowed:

```
Author | Album name
-------------------
Johny  | FireGrasp
Johny  | FireGrasp
```

This should BE allowed:

```
Author | Album name
-------------------
Johny  | FireGrasp
Mandy  | FireGrasp
```

Should I make procedure for it?

I will try to explain it by how code should work:

```
insert into Author(Val) VALUES ('John'), ('Mandy');

-- Author_id: 3=John, 4=Marx
insert into Album(Val, Author_id) VALUES ('Firegrasp', 3);
insert into Album(Val, Author_id) VALUES ('Firegrasp', 3); -- This should not work now
insert into Album(Val, Author_id) VALUES ('Firegrasp', 4); -- This should work
```

Comment: If you make a unique index that's on the columns Author and Album name, SQL will prevent insertion of a row if that author and album name already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether You want to create a table (OR) you looking for query to get the posted output.

If you are looking for creating a table then you can make `Author,Album name` as `primary key` (`composite PK`) which will make sure that combination of `Author + Album name` will always be unique. `primary key(Author, [Album name])`

You can even create a multicolumn unique constraint like `unique(Author, [Album name])` in case you already have a `PK` defined in your table.

(OR)

If you are looking for a query for getting those desired result then I think you can simply use `distinct` keyword which will get you only one of those two record.

Considering, your `Album` table has only this two columns `(Val, Author_id)`; create a primary key like

```
create table Album
(Val varchar(20),Author_id int,
CONSTRAINT PK_composite_123 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Val, Author_id))
```

Comment: I have edited my first post, look at code please :)

It's about unique **combination** of values in columns

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek, my answer exactly address the question you have. Either create a PK for columns `Val, Author_id` (OR) create a unique constraint for those columns.